# ControlTemplate.Triggers WPF equivalent in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, triggers, vsm

I have this controltempalte + trigger stuff in my WPF application.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="me:MyControl" x:Key="fade">
    <ContentPresenter - other stuff />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsTransitioned" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation -<stuff>- />                                
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works cool in WPF, and is very intuitive too for me to write this based on trigger as above.

When i port this to Silverlight (3), i am told i have to use VSM, states and groups etc. since triggers on control template is not supported. 
I h ave looked at some samples, and i even atempted to apply teh VSM bits in, in the place of trigger as above, but can't get it to work.

Someone suggested to me that apart from VSM in the xaml, i will have to handle some events etc.

SL3 model is just being painful for me. Please help.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason part of my post is not being rendered...
i.e. this bit on top of my code snippet...

<ControlTemplate TargetType="me:MyControl" x:Key="fade">
        <ContentPresenter - other stuff /> 

But anywya, you get the idea of my problem.. which is more important :-)

Comment: All the code needs to be indented by 4 spaces so SO knows it's a code snippet. Quickest way to do this is to select all your code in Visual Studio and press tab before you copy it over. I think otherwise it think it's supposed to be some HTML and as it's not it ignores it.

Comment: Thanks mattmanser. Thnx for the indenting tip :-) I have fixed my code bits now :-)

Answer (score 11):

Silverlight 3 introduced interaction triggers which as far as I can tell do what you want but are a little more complex. There's very few examples about them out yet though.

If you're doing this manually you need references to System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions (from Blend 3, the class will be in your references tab if you've installed it).

If you add the triggers in Blend then it will add those automatically. This is called Behaviours in Silverlight 3 and you will find these in Blend in the Behaviours section of the Assets tab.

An example of how they work. Note the storyboard sitting in the resource of the second rectangle, I couldn't get it to work inside the ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard, but it did work if I made the rectangle a ContentControl and put it in the Template. This may be a bug or me missing something :

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    x:Class="SLTrigger.MainPage"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" 
    xmlns:im="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Margin="5" Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="100">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <ic:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Fill" Duration="0">
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                        </ic:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </ic:ChangePropertyAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Margin="5" x:Name="AnimatedRectangle2" Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="100">
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationStoryboard">
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRectangle2"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        To="Red"
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Rectangle.Resources>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <im:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play" Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimationStoryboard}">
                        <!--
                        Doesn't work, but does work inside control templates??
                        <im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRectangle2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="Red"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                        -->
                    </im:ControlStoryboardAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="5" x:Name="AnimatedRectangle3" Fill="Blue" Width="200" Height="100">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <im:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                                    <im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRectangle3"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="Red"
                                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                </im:ControlStoryboardAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Rectangle>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
        </ContentControl>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Click the rectangles" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The class file has nothing in it:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SLTrigger
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great stuff. OK so still it is an event trigger, and there is still no way for a property trigger? In that case, can i just raise a custom event in the control when that property changes, and use the "interaction" based event trigger that you have shown above? Would that work? Somehow i need to get the storyboard to work (in XAML) when the property's value in my control changes. I don't want to code it in C#. I want to keep it in XAML as-is now.

Comment: I know this question is old but, Silverlight 4 now has additional triggers including a property changed trigger.

Comment: Why did no one ever +1 this answer before me?