# Equivalent to WPF ControlTemplate.Triggers in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight-4.0

The below is my WPF ControlTemplate.Triggers and i have changed the code in silverlight with the Interactivity.Interaction.Triggers and it is not working .
can anyone pls help me.

WPF Code:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                   Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

My Silverligh code:

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>                   
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="HasItems" >
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DropDownBorder" PropertyName="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                    <i:EventTrigger SourceName="Popup" >
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DropDownBorder" PropertyName="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DropDownBorder" PropertyName="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Popup.AllowsTransparency">
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="Border" PropertyName="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="Border" PropertyName="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="Border" PropertyName="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Silverlignt code one thing i got is ....

```
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="HasItems" >    
                     <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DropDownBorder"    
                      PropertyName="MinHeight" Value="95" />                     
</i:EventTrigger>
```

i believe `HasItems` is not an event its a property

[Check this Answer and the comments too :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249537/controltemplate-triggers-wpf-equivalent-in-silverlight-3) and this [link](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/02/08/silverlight-4-property-triggers/) also might help....

Comment: Ya you are correct it is not an event ..Is there any other way to handle this and also i will check those link..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use [Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.EXPRESSION.INTERACTIVITY.CORE.DATATRIGGER%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true) (which is the equivalent of Trigger) rather than EventTrigger.